# Отказ работы скрипта после замены html-содержимого на идентичное методом ajax

Tags: html, jquery, ajax

Есть выпадающее меню [такого](https://jsfiddle.net/8nprka6y/1/) типа. Таких пунктов у меня не два а больше, открывает и скрывает их один и тот же скрипт. После выполнения ajax-запроса мне сервер передаёт новое содержимое `<li class="active active_right" id="cart">`Структура html классы всё абсолютно идентичное, меняется только текст. После этого обновления скрипт отказывается раскрывать этот пункт меню, с другими всё работает. Если страницу обновить, то скрипт начинает работать и с этим пунктом меню

Comment: возможно вы забыли снова повесить обработчики на `.dropdown-toggle`

Comment: @KaZaца а как это сделать?

Comment: Спасибо большое. Разобрался

Answer (score 1, accepted):

после обновления html-контента обработчики "слетают". вам необходимо, после окончания ajax запроса и обновления контента заново их навесить, т.е. выполнить

```
$('.dropdown-toggle').click(function(e) {...
```

Comment: то есть скрипт выпадающего меню прописать ещё и в `success`?

Comment: Спасибо. Понял. Запихал код в функцию и вызвал её после выполнения запроса